# Google Sheets script to send Email: If background color of cell is #00ff00, take email from next column and send mail there

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code checks if a cell from Q4 to Q20 is green. Now I want to send an email to an emailadress (which is on the same row as the the green marked cell), every time a cell is green. I need a code which sees ah ok for example Q5 is green -> go to E5 -> take mail address and send mail to the address and this from Q4 to Q20. Maybe someone has an idea what to put in that IF

```
function automatednotifications() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    
    var range = sheet.getRange("Q4:Q20");
    var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
    
    for (var i in bgColors) {
      for (var j in bgColors[i]) {
        if (bgColors[i][j] === '#00ff00') {
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... idea ti put in that IF-Statement at the end

Comment: check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code, you can modify your code as following:

```
...
var range = sheet.getRange("Q4:Q20");
var values = sheet.getRange("E4:E20").getValues().flat();
...
    if (bgColors[i][j] === '#00ff00') {
     var email = values[i];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "subject", "body");
    }
...
```

Note:

- Since your emails are all in one column, you can reduce the 2D value range to a 1D array with [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), so you need to loop only through `i` and not `j`
- You could do the same for `bgColorsbgColors  so you would need only one instead of two` for` loops (would make your code simpler adn faster).

References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getvalues)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)

Comment: Is it possible for you to put what you have sent right into my code and send it back to me? I am very new to coding in excel so i don’t really understand where to put your code :)